# $\forall a,b \in {\mathbb R^+}$: if $a=b$ then $\sqrt a =\sqrt b$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Is this statement:

$\forall a,b \in {\mathbb R^+}$: if $a=b$ then $\sqrt a =\sqrt b$

True or False? If False, then how?

I know we could take $a = b = 9$ and then continue with $ 9 = (-3)^2 = 3^2$ and try that. But my professor said in class that the negative sign arises 'externally' or when we use the convention $\pm4$ when square rooting a number, say, $16$ it comes from outside. This has got me pretty confused.

Comment: If $a= b$ then *any* statement involving $a$ will be true if it is said about $b$.  So true.

Comment: @fleablood +1 That is an incredibly intuitive way to deal with this question.

Comment: to be honest, I'm perplexed that there is any *other* way to think of the question.  Even if we make some weird assumption/definition that a square root can flip back and forth between positive and negative values we can't say "The square root of 9 will be 3 when we use one variable but it will be 9 when we use a different variable".  I wonder if the question was supposed to go the other way.  If $\sqrt a = \sqrt b$ then $a = b$, true false?  (Hint: true... but not without a reason.)

Answer (score 3):

The square root is a *function* from $[0,+\infty[$ to $[0,+\infty[$. For any function $f$, if $a=b$, then $f(a)=f(b)$ (provided $f$ is defined at $a$).

Your professor is probably referring to the situation where you look for solutions of the equation $x^2=a$ with $a\ge0$, and then there are two solutions, $+\sqrt{a}$ and $-\sqrt{a}$. But the sign is not "part" of the function $x\to\sqrt x$.

Answer (score 3):

$x^2 = 4$ has two solutions

i.e. $x = 2$ and $x = -2$

But $\sqrt 4 = 2$ and $\sqrt 4 \ne - 2$

Which means that $\sqrt x$ is not exactly the inverse operation of $x^2$

We have defined the radical ($\sqrt{}$ symbol) to always refer to the "principal root."  This means for one input we get one output.  And, $\sqrt x$ is a function.

And if we indeed want to refer to both roots we need the  $\pm$ prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the square root sign means the positive value only, so $\sqrt{9} = 3$. However, whether or not you want both the positive and negative solutions *depends on the context in which you are finding the square root*. For example, in the quadratic formula you want both, hence
$$
ax^{2} + bx + c = 0 \iff x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2} - 4ac}}{2a}.
$$
Observe that we specify we want both roots with the $\pm$ sign.

For this reason, if $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, then it is true that $\sqrt{a} = \sqrt{b}$. However, the set of solutions to $a^{2} = b^{2}$ is $a = \pm b$. The reason that we are finding square roots tells us whether we need to consider the negative counterpart as well.

Answer (score 1):

By convention the $\sqrt{M}$ refers *specifically* to the *positive* square root of $M$.  So if $a=b=9$ then $\sqrt{a} = \sqrt{b} = \sqrt{9} = 3\ne -3$ even though $(-3)^2 = 9$.  Just because $x^2 = k$ does NOT mean $x = \sqrt {k}$.  It means $|x| =\sqrt {k}$ and $x =$ *either* $\sqrt{k}$ or $-\sqrt{k}$ but not both.

But that's irrelevent.

Even if we were to define something else (and math is *only* definitions ) as $squareroot(9) =\{3,-3\}$ so $squareroot(k)=\{$ all things $x$ so that $x^2 = k\}$.  Then if $a = b$ then $squareroot(a) = squareroot(b)$.

The thing is, if $a = b$ than $a$ and $b$ are *the same thing*.  So *whatever* you say about $a$ *has* to be the same as you say about $b$.  So $\mu^{\omega}_{gumpty}(a) = \mu^{\omega}_{gumpty}(b)$ even if you have not freaking idea what $\mu^{\omega}_{gumpty}(x)$ means.